# DbContext.DbSet.FromSql() not accepting parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database with two tables, and wrote a relatively simple select statement that combines the data and returns me the fields I want. In my SQL developer software it executes just fine.

Now to execute it in my C# .NET Core application, I created a "fake" DbSet in my DbContext that doesn't have a proper table on the database. The Type of the DbSet is a Model that represents the resulting data structure of the select statement. I use the DbSet field to access the method `FromSql()` and execute the select like so:

```
List<ProjectSearchModel> results = _ejContext.ProjectSearch.FromSql(
    @"SELECT combined.Caption, combined.Number FROM 
        (SELECT p.Caption, p.Number, CreateDate FROM dbo.Project AS p
        UNION
        SELECT j.Caption, j.Number, CreateDate  FROM dbo.Job AS j) AS combined
    WHERE combined.Caption LIKE '{0}%' OR combined.Number LIKE '{0}%'
    ORDER BY combined.CreateDate DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH FIRST 30 ROWS ONLY", term)
    .ToList();
```

The SQL does properly return data, I've tested that. But the `result` variable holds 0 entries after executing. In the documentation for `FromSql()` I found that with MS SQL Servers you have to use `OFFSET 0` when using `ORDER BY` so that's what I did.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DbQuery<T>` instead:

```
public DbQuery<Project> ProjectSearch { get; set; }
```

Then, you can issue arbitrary queries using `FromSql` on that. With `DbSet`, the query must be composable, which means it can only be a standard select, it must correspond to a real table, and must include all properties on the entity - none of which apply to the query you're trying to perform.

Comment: ohh I didn't even know that's a thing. thanks a lot! I'm gonna start reading up on the DbQuery class, though I still don't get any results.

Answer (score 0):

As @ChrisPratt said, one of my mistakes was using the `DbSet` class instead of the `DbQuery` class. But also, what drove me crazy is that my parameters didn't work. My mistake was putting them inside a string, which results in them not being recognized as parameters. So my SQL string should be

```
...
WHERE combined.Caption LIKE {0} + '%' OR combined.Number LIKE {0} + '%'
...
```

instead of

```
...
WHERE combined.Caption LIKE '{0}%' OR combined.Number LIKE '{0}%'
...
```